# Ord: No type class instance was found for Data.Eq.Eq (Extended a0). PureScript by Example book, Chapter 6

Tags: typeclass, purescript

I am quite new to Haskell/Purescript and currently learning by studying the [PureScript by Example book](https://book.purescript.org/).

In [chapter 6](https://book.purescript.org/chapter6.html) about type classes, [exercise 4](https://book.purescript.org/chapter6.html#exercises-2) has following task:

> (Medium) Given any type `a` with an instance of `Ord`, we can add a new "infinite" value which is greater than any other value:
>
> ```
> data Extended a = Finite a | Infinite
> ```
>
> Write an `Ord` instance for `Extended a` which reuses the `Ord` instance for `a`.

Here is my attempt:

```
instance ordExtended :: Ord a => Ord (Extended a) where
  compare Infinite Infinite = EQ
  compare Infinite _ = GT
  compare _ Infinite = LT
  compare (Finite f1) (Finite f2) = compare f1 f2
```

Unfortunately, the code triggers an error:

> No type class instance was found for
>
> Data.Eq.Eq (Extended a0)
>
> while checking that expression #dict Eq
> has type { eq :: Extended a0 -> Extended a0 -> Boolean
> }
> in value declaration ordExtended
>
> where a0 is a rigid type variable
> bound at (line 0, column 0 - line 0, column 0)
> PureScript(NoInstanceFound)

I cannot quite  understand the error message:

1. What does `expression #dict Eq` mean? There is no `dict` in my code.
2. What is a *rigid* type variable?
3. The error seems to use different identifiers like `a0` (why? I assume, that is `a`)

In my book, `Eq` type class instance should be covered by implementing `Ord`, as `Ord` extends `Eq`.

Comment: Haskell is not purescript. I don't know why you're tagging a purescript question with Haskell.

Comment: @Aplet123 At least from what I have read yet, much of the syntax/language features of Purescript are nearly equivalent to Haskell (like the type class feature). Hence the thought is,  this question might be also answered by someone experienced with Haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key part of the error is at the start:

```
No type class instance was found for

    Data.Eq.Eq (Extended a0)
```

Here is the definition of `Ord`:

```
class Eq a <= Ord a where
  compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
```

This is actually the [superclass](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Type-Classes.md#superclasses) syntax, saying that you need an `Eq` instance to have an `Ord` instance. So, you can fix the error by making an `Eq` instance:

```
instance eqExtended :: Eq a => Eq (Extended a) where
  eq Infinite Infinite = true
  eq (Finite f1) (Finite f2) = eq f1 f2
  eq _ _ = false

instance ordExtended :: Ord a => Ord (Extended a) where
  compare Infinite Infinite = EQ
  compare Infinite _ = GT
  compare _ Infinite = LT
  compare (Finite f1) (Finite f2) = compare f1 f2
```

As to why `a0` is used, it seems the purescript compiler just likes adding numbers after type variables, possibly to reduce vagueness or to allow for scoped type variables. You can [read about rigid type variables here](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-November/111397.html) (they're basically variables that can't be changed to fit constraints).

Comment: Ah, I had the wrong assumption, constraining type variable `a` to `Ord` would be sufficient to make `Extended` an instance of `Ord` (and transitively of `Eq`). Thanks!